# Вывод элементов массива через if?

Tags: javascript

```
let mass = {
    "a": {
        c1: "aaaa",
        c2: "bbbb",
        c7: "ffff",
        с4: "deeee"
    },

    "b": {
        c1: "ccc",
        c2: "dddd",
        c10: "tttt",
        с40: "deeee"
    },

    "c": {
        c1: "ffff",
        c2: "kkkk",
        c7: "xxxx"
    }
}
```

1. Как сделать так, чтобы вывелись c1, c2 и c7? 
   c1, c2 - обязательные во всех массивах, c7 - нет.
   чтобы вывести просто c1, c2,я могу перебрать через цикл. а что добавить, чтобы выводились только c1, c2 и c7?
   for (let k in mass)

то есть, чтобы я на выходе получил
a: c1, c2, c7
b: c1, c2
c: c1, c2, c7

2. Как обратиться ко всем элементам, чтобы вывести абсолютно все содержимым массивов a,b,c?

   a: c1, c2, c7, c4
   b: c1, c2, c10, c40
   c: c1, c2, c7

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать так, чтобы вывелись c1, c2 и c7 ?

Обращение к несуществующему ключу не выдает ошибку, а просто возвращает undefined, который в логическом контексте будет false. Поэтому в некоторых случаях можно обойтись проверкой

`if ( obj.c7 ) { /*...*/ }`

Подвох: Если такой ключ есть, но со значениями `null, 0, "", NaN, undefined` — это всё тоже false, поэтому есть вероятность, что какой-нибудь ключ `{c7: 0}` не пройдет проверку.

Наличие ключа в объекте можно проверить через `объект.hasOwnProperty("ключ")`

```js
let obj = {
  "a": {c1: "aaaa", c2: "bbbb", c7: "ffff"},
  "b": {c1: "cccc", c2: "dddd", c9: "tttt"},
  "c": {c1: "ffff", c2: "kkkk", c7: "xxxx"}
};

for( let key in obj ) {
  let tmp = {};
  
  tmp.c1 = obj[key].c1;
  tmp.c2 = obj[key].c2;
  
  if( obj[key].hasOwnProperty('c7') ) {
    tmp.c7 = obj[key].c7;
  }
  
  obj[key] = tmp;
}

console.log(obj);
```

> Как вывести абсолютно все содержимое a,b,c?

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) - возвращает массив, со всеми значениями переданного объекта.

```js
let bubu = {
  "a": {c1: "aaaa", c2: "bbbb", c7: "ffff"},
  "b": {c1: "cccc", c2: "dddd", c9: "tttt"},
  "c": {c1: "ffff", c2: "kkkk", c7: "xxxx"}
};

let arr = Object.values(bubu).map(Object.values).flat();

console.log(arr);

// console.log( Object.values(bubu) );
// console.log( Object.keys(bubu) );
```

В этом случае, values() возвращает такой массив:

```
[
  {c1: "aaaa", c2: "bbbb", c7: "ffff"},
  {c1: "cccc", c2: "dddd", c9: "tttt"},
  {c1: "ffff", c2: "kkkk", c7: "xxxx"}
]
```

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - берет функцию, применяет её к кажому элементу массива и подменяет этот элемент на результат вызова функции. А результат вызова `Object.values` → массив со значениями `["aaaa","bbbb","ffff"]` и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Приклажываю два котика

Первый выводит только с1, с2 и с7, если он имеется

```js
const mass = {
    a: {c1: 'aaaa', c2: 'bbbb', c7: 'ffff', с4: 'deeee'},
    b: {c1: 'ccc', c2: 'dddd', c10: 'tttt', с40: 'deeee'},
    c: {c1: 'ffff', c2: 'kkkk', c7: 'xxxx'}
};

let summ = '';
for(let one in mass){
    summ += `${one}: ${mass[one].c1} ${mass[one].c2} ${mass[one].c7 ? mass[one].c7 : ''}\n`;
}

console.log(summ);
```

Второй котик - выводит `все данные - всех объедков` в `главном объедке`

```js
const mass = {
    a: {c1: 'aaaa', c2: 'bbbb', c7: 'ffff', с4: 'deeee'},
    b: {c1: 'ccc', c2: 'dddd', c10: 'tttt', с40: 'deeee'},
    c: {c1: 'ffff', c2: 'kkkk', c7: 'xxxx'}
};

let summ = '';
for(let one in mass){
    let keys = Object.entries(mass[one]);
    keys = keys.flatMap((e)=>e.join(': '));
    summ += `${one}: [${keys.join(' | ')}]\n`;
}

console.log(summ);
```

Также попробуй это:

```js
console.log(Object.values(mass).flatMap(Object.values)); // абсолютно всё содержимое
```